# How can I scroll 100% of the viewport? (Responsive on each Device)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this one pager with 4 different sections. And a menu with 4 different buttons (each one for each section). I wanted to smooth scroll on all. The way i tried is to give each  a href, which is the id of each title but the problem then is that the menu covers half of the title  (see pic) because of its fixed position. See the code snippet to see what I tried next.

```js
function goToPageOne() {
  if(window.innerHeight > 728 && window.innerWidth < 500) {
    window.scrollTo(0,700);
  } else {
    window.scrollTo(0,689);
  }
}
document.getElementById("me").addEventListener("click", goToPageOne);
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a id="me">Me</a>
        <a id="timeline">Timeline</a>
        <a id="work">My work</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
```

The problem with this that it's not really a responsive function for all devices.

[image]

Comment: Please, if you include a snippet, click on Run code snippet and see if it reproduces your issue. The current snippet does not appear to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking to your sections, you could link to anchors which you intentionally move above the section.

Demo:

```css
/* For the demo */
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top: 20px; }
#myTopnav { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; background: #f1f1f1; }
#myTopnav a { display: inline-block; padding: .8em; }
section { height: 400px; padding: .5em; }
section:nth-of-type(even) { background: #333; color: #fff; }

.anchor {
  position: relative;
  top: -45px; /* <-------- */
}
```

```html
<div id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#me">Me</a>
  <a href="#timeline">Timeline</a>
  <a href="#work">My work</a>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="anchor" id="home"></div>
  <h2>Home</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="anchor" id="me"></div>
  <h2>Me</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="anchor" id="timeline"></div>
  <h2>Timeline</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="anchor" id="work"></div>
  <h2>Work</h2>
</section>
```